# Indefinite article with the word "meal"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Do I need an indefinite article in the following sentence?

> I wouldn't call it **a** healthful meal

And if I do, could I still drop it?

Will it sound terribly awkward if I drop it?

Comment: The article is necessary. Other than in special cases like newspaper headlines, you cannot drop articles in English. It's ungrammatical if you drop the "a".

Comment: In BrE at least, "a healthy meal" would be preferred. Separate question, though.

Comment: What @RogerLipscombe says is true nowadays. Prescriptivists will argue that "healthy" can only be applied to people, and "healthful" only to food, but no one says "healthful" at all anymore (similar situation to "naseous" and "nauseated"). AmE speaker here.

Comment: Oxford's Learner's Dictionaries says that it "healthful" is "formal or North American English" insinuating that it is a formal usage in Britain that North Americans may have hyper-corrected into regular use. Merriam-Webster doesn't make any remarks about it. All in all it seems like a fine word that is available in contemporary English dialects.

Comment: I've never heard the word healthful in my life prior to this that I recall. I think most BrE speakers would find it jarring. It's understandable but I'd imagine most people would think you'd just invented a new word

Comment: "Will it sound terribly awkward if I drop it?" — yes, I'd say not using articles correctly is one of the biggest tells of non-fluent speakers.

Comment: 'Oxford's Learner's Dictionaries says that it "healthful" is "formal or North American English" insinuating' -- this characterization is pretty outdated I think. I almost never hear "healthful" in the US. "healthy" is very commonly applied to objects and not only people in US English.

Comment: Let's clear up a few things.  1) BrE speaker's English is not a great standard... let Pygmalion really sink in. 2) Healthful is not typical of North American English either. 3) It is also really isn't so exotic that that any English speaker, BrE or otherwise, would care unless attention were called to it.  Usage of 'healthful' peaked in the 1850s, but the term 'healthful diet' seems to be having a 2nd peak right now according to Google ngrams.  The particular term 'healthful meal' is quite rare. Webster's has a bit to say: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/healthy-or-healthful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need an article to avoid ambiguity. *Meal* as a substance means ground-up grains (e.g. oatmeal).

Comment: But even if I meant substance would I still not need the indefinite article? (look, even in your answer you still used "a" before the word "substance")

Comment: No, you wouldn't - with that meaning, it's an uncountable noun.

Comment: But "substance" is also uncountable. An yet you used "a" with it.

Comment: No, it isn't. _A substance_ is _one_ particular kind of material. Meal is a substance, _a_ meal is an occasion when you eat a quantity of food.

Comment: Aah! I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: "Meal" is ground-up *food*, not necessarily grain. Read the ingredients on a bag of pet kibble some time; chicken meal, bone meal, meat meal, etc. are just as "real" as oat meal, corn meal, rice meal, etc. (Oatmeal and cornmeal are usually expressed as single words.) Etymologically, "meal" is just "food that has been milled".

Comment: While the "a" does disambiguate, that's not the reason why you need the "a". Even if there isn't any alternative uncountable noun meaning, you would still need the article: e.g. "I wouldn't call it beautiful aeroplane" is not grammatical (substitute other nouns as desired).

Comment: @R.M. It does work with meal, since that has an uncountable version. Airplane doesn't.

Comment: @jaxad0127 My point is that "you need an article to avoid ambiguity" is slightly misleading. Yes, having the article disambiguates, but the ambiguity is not why you _need_ the article. Even if there wasn't an uncountable version, you'd still need the article. It's not optional, even in cases with no ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

"Meal" is a common noun. There are lots of meals. I eat 3 a day, at least. You need the article if you are singling out just one meal (or one *type* of meal). If you dropped it, it would be wrong.